# Dynamic grid creation

Tags: python

I am trying to make a 2d grid in python. The size of the grid can vary but the largest it could be is 20 X 20 and the content of a given list should be printed inside each cell that has a width of 4 field spaces. The contents in the left-most cels should be left centred and the contents in the far most cells should be right centred and the rest should be centred inside of the cells
Here is my code:

```
def first(a):
    print('+', end = ' ')
    for i in range(a-1):
        print('%4s%s' %('-','+'), end = ' ')
    print('%4s%s' %('-','+'))

def second(list_):
    for index in list_:
        print('|', end = ' ')
        for num in index:
            print('%s%d%2s|' %('', num, ''), end = ' ')
        print('%4s|' %(''))  

def create_(a,b,list_):
    first(a)
    for i in range(b):
        second(list_)
        first(a)
list_ = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
create_(3,3,list_)

The output of the code is:
+    -+      -+       -+      -+
|  1  |    2  |   3    |       |
|  4  |    5  |   6    |       |
|  7  |    8  |   9    |       |
.... (this is because it repeats 4 more times)
+    -+      -+       -+      -+
|  1  |    2  |   3    |       |
|  4  |    5  |   6    |       |
|  7  |    8  |   9    |       |
+    -+      -+       -+      -+
And the output that I want is 
+----------------+
|1   |  2  |    3|
+----+-----+-----+
|4   |  5  |    6|
+----+-----+-----+
|7   |  8  |    9|
+----------------+
```

My problem is obviously, my output is not the same but also
is how can I code this more dynamically where it produces the expected grid no matter how many columns or rows it was given, I've kinda hardcoded things to get my output which I don't think is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and easy to understand:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for ind, L in enumerate(data):
    
    if ind == 0:
        print("+"+(("----"*len(L))[:-1])+"+")
    else:
        print("+---"*len(L)+"+")

    for ind2, I in enumerate(L):
        if ind2 == 0:
            print(f"|{I}  ", end="|")
        elif ind2 == len(L)-1:
            print(f"  {I}", end="|")
        else:
            print(f" {I} ", end="|")
    print()
        
    
print("+"+(("----"*len(L))[:-1])+"+")
```

output:

```
+-----------+
|1  | 2 |  3|
+---+---+---+
|4  | 5 |  6|
+---+---+---+
|7  | 8 |  9|
+-----------+
```

You can also use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_row_split(inner_list_):
    return  '+' + '+'.join('-' * 5 for _ in inner_list_) + '+' + '\n'

def get_row(inner_list_):
    cells = []
    for i, _  in enumerate(inner_list_):
        if i == 0:
            cell = "{}    "
        elif i + 1 == len(inner_list_):
            cell = "    {}"
        else:
            cell = "  {}  "
        cells.append(cell)
    return '|' + '|'.join(
        cell.format(str(item)) for cell, item in zip(cells, inner_list_)
    ) + '|' + '\n'


def main():
    list_ = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,6],[7,8,9,8]]
    output = ""
    for inner_list_ in list_:
        output += get_row_split(inner_list_ = inner_list_)
        output += get_row(inner_list_ = inner_list_)
    output += get_row_split(inner_list_ = inner_list_)
    print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|1    |  2  |  3  |    4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|4    |  5  |  6  |    6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|7    |  8  |  9  |    8|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The only thing is that this will break if the numbers are double or more digit. Not sure if there is a way to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
num_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def grid_parser(ls):
    width = len(ls[0])
    height = len(ls)
    fin_list = []
    sep_line = '+'+'+'.join(['-----',]*width)+'+'
    fin_list.append(sep_line)
    for line in range(height):
        line_lis = []
        for elem in range(width):
            if elem == 0:
                line_lis.append("{el:<5}".format(el=ls[line][elem]))
            elif elem == width-1:
                line_lis.append("{el:>5}".format(el=ls[line][elem]))
            else:
                line_lis.append("{el:^5}".format(el=ls[line][elem]))
        wh_line = '|'+'|'.join(line_lis)+'|'
        fin_list.append(wh_line)
        fin_list.append(sep_line)
    for i in fin_list:
        print(i)
    
grid_parser(num_list)
```

output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|1    |  2  |    3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|4    |  5  |    6|
+-----+-----+-----+
|7    |  8  |    9|
+-----+-----+-----+
```